# Solution for streaming data (Java, Python, socket.io, Node JS)

Tags: java, python, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm working on a project where I need to stream financial data to a web browser. I got a Java API from the data provider (I'm not strong in Java) with which I can stream the data to my server. When the data comes in I need to do some calculations on it and store it in a MongoDB database and also send it to any connected clients. If I don't want to use Java what are my best options to build a solution?  I was thinking about socket.io with Node but not sure how I could monitor the stream and at the same time store the data and stream it to connected clients.

The current technology stack is: MongoDB, Python and Node JS.

Thanks,
Dirk

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that i haven't actually worked with this personally, but at work we used this:

http://www.fluentd.org/

it might more or less accommodate your needs. It might be what you need to catch the data from that Java API that you have and pipe it to wherever you want it.

just as a heads up, plugins aren't really that great, we kinda had a lot problems with them.

Comment: Thanks thecodeflavour, I had a quick look at it and looks more like a solution to handle logs?